# choose particular DOM to Slide

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some **itemBox**，I need to click **itemBox** and call the **workItem** which has same id number to SildeUp(the workItem is hidden at the beginning).

When one of **workItem** SlideUp，others would be hidden.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="itemBox" id="item0">
                <img src="img/default.jpg" alt="">
                <div>titletitle</div>
            </div>

            <div class="itemBox" id="item1">
                <img src="img/default.jpg" alt="">
                <div>titletitle</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="workContent">
    <div class="workItem" id="work0" style="background-color:#000000;">
        <h2>demo1</h2>
        <img src="img/default.jpg" alt="">
        <div>contentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontent</div>
        <div>contentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontent</div>
        <div>contentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontent</div>
        <div>contentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontent</div>
    </div>

    <div class="workItem" id="work1" style="background-color:#333333;">
        <a class="close" href="javascript:">x</a>
        <h2>demo2</h2>
        <img src="img/default.jpg" alt="">
        <div>contentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontent</div>
        <div>contentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontent</div>
        <div>contentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontent</div>
        <div>contentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontent</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I do this with javascript or Jquery?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! 
Have you tried anything so far? 
StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to 
[try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). 
Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a 
[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
For further information, please see 
[how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
and take the 
[tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

this is simple (i used jQuery):

```
$(".itemBox").click (function(){
   $("div[id^=work]").hide();
   var id = $(this).attr("id");
   var number = id.match(/item([0-9]+)/));
   if (number[1])
      $("div[id=work" + number[1] + "]").show();
})
```